# The DocumentRoot in Ubuntu's apache is /var/www/html so why would apache2.conf have part of it say "<Directory /var/www/>"

Tags: apache2

The DocumentRoot in Ubuntu's apache is /var/www/html  so why would apache2.conf have part of it say "<Directory /var/www/>"

Extract from the default apache2.conf on ubuntu's apache.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I understand that the `"<Directory...>"` line is to protect a directory.  But

If DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html` (which it is on ubuntu's apache, or at least is in apache in the current ubuntu), then  surely `/var/www` wouldn't get exposed anyway. So what's to protect re that?

Comment: Besides what Marc has said there is also a `<Directory />` line with ` Require all denied
` in apache.org's suggested minimal configuration, or in  ubuntu's distro apache in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf`  (maybe to cater for a potential crazy value for DocumentRoot? eg in a virtualhost file or more oddly if in the main config file, apache2.conf?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the `Directory` directive is defined outside a `VirtualHost` directive the settings will apply to all virtual hosts.
- `Directory` directives also apply to subdirectories

So all this does is applying these settings as a default to all subdirectories and  virtual hosts living inside `/var/www`

Since a single httpd instance often serves content for more then one domain, the directory structure often looks like this `/var/www/[vhost]/html`. So it makes sense to have a `Directory` directive like this to define sane standard values

Comment: And consider why it doesn't say `<Directory /var>` ?.   Surely it makes more sense for it to only be on  `<Directory /var/www/html>`  or some subdirectory of that.

Comment: the homedir for _www-data_ (the user which is usually running the httpd) is `/var/www` and content is supposed to be served from there. therefore it makes sense to define these settings for `/var/www` (and subdirectories) and not for `/var`

Comment: A) When you say "home directory for www-data", do you actually mean DocumentRoot? And B) did you see the question said that "The DocumentRoot in Ubuntu's apache is /var/www/html "

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.. so each VirtualHost would have its own DocumentRoot /var/www/domain  (overriding the default DocumentRoot), And then it'd make sense to have <Directory /var/www>.  Would you agree?

Comment: thats what i said, yes.